# Sort date in format MMM d, yyyy

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have object like this,

```
 {
Nov 17, 2016:Array[1]
Dec 1, 2016:Array[1]
Nov 22, 2016:Array[1]
Nov 23, 2016:Array[1]
Nov 21, 2016:Array[1]
}
```

i want to sort this as descending order in the same date format.
output should be... Thank's in advance.

```
{
 Dec 1, 2016:Array[1]
 Nov 23, 2016:Array[1]
 Nov 22, 2016:Array[1]
 Nov 21, 2016:Array[1]
 Nov 17, 2016:Array[1]
}
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/kZzxHDg1om7ylbGYeloe?p=preview
[plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/kZzxHDg1om7ylbGYeloe?p=preview)

Comment: is that a valid json?

Comment: i dont understand to variables type...if is JSON, that wrongs...

Comment: No this is not a valid json format, but i am getting object like this.

Comment: see this link ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10123953/sort-javascript-object-array-by-date

Comment: i have a plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/kZzxHDg1om7ylbGYeloe?p=preview better way to go thorough this.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to put

> ng-repeat="message in data.messages | orderBy:'createdTime':true"

It will order your data in descending order of **createdTime**

```
<div class="panel panel-default"  ng-repeat="message in data.messages | orderBy:'createdTime':true">
   <div class="panel-heading" style="color:blue">{{ message.createdTime | date:'MMM d, yyyy' }}</div>
   <div class="panel-body" >
       <span  uib-tooltip="{{message.userName}}" tooltip-placement="top">{{ message.groupList[0].userName }}, {{ message.groupList[1].userName }}</span>
   </div>
</div>
```

Check

https://plnkr.co/edit/CbV3uQI8JoU2Wt0wFsSl?p=preview

Comment: Thanks 4 answered @Ali Mehdi , but my requirement doesn't meet with your answer. I have filtered data as **GroupByDate** 4 the purpose of comparison with **current date & prev date to show today & yesterday** respectively. and **groupList** may contain more or less than two objects.It shouldn't be like messages.groupList[0].